# Updating List <HashMap>

Tags: android, list, hashmap

I just want to know how to, if a Hashmap is already on the list add 1 to quantity, if it is not then add it to list. This is what I've done that just add eventhough the item is already on list.

```
list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT code,desc,price FROM TbLPrice WHERE code =" + txtCode.getText().toString(), null);  //search database
                if (c.moveToFirst()){ //if successful
                    txtDesc.setText(c.getString(1)); //get desc 
                    txtPrice.setText(c.getString(2)); // get price @ database
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("desc", c.getString(1));
                    map.put("price", c.getString(2));
                    map.put("quantity","1");
                    list.add(map);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: What do you really try to achieve with this? If you explain what problem you want to solve, it might be easier to understand your code. Because as of now, it doesn't make much sense...

Comment: Please take a look at my solution below. Before adding an item in a list, I want to know if it already exist, if not, add the item on list, if it already exists, update its hashmap "quantity" to 2 and so on.

Comment: I had already looked at your solution below when writing my first comment. And I repeat: what do you really want to achieve with this? Your code is not easy to read (and it seems like the code is part of a bigger context), so it is hard to understand, and thus hard to help you. Why for instance do you have several ´HashMap´ inside an ´ArrayList´? Do you try to sum something perhaps? Because if that is the case, I feel I'm missing a loop or something... Try to clean up your code and clarify your question (perhaps with a concrete example), then we might be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry about my code. I am still new to android. I have a list that will store a hashmap with [desc,price,quantity]. I want to add an element inside the list but before I add, I want to check if same item exist first because if it already exist. I wont add another element but update the quantity of the same item. ex. 
DESC     PRICE     QUANTITY
ITEM A     10.00     1
ITEM B     20.00     1

if i want to add another ITEM A, It already exist on the list so I just want to add 1 to the quantity of Item A that is already in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your last comment, I think I see what you're trying to do. Firstly, I would create a small class holding the information about your items, to make it a bit easier to work with (I've only implemented the necessary setters, you'll probably want some getters (and other functions) as well):

```
public class MyItem
{
    String description;
    float price;
    int quantity;

    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity)
    {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public void increaseQuantity()
    {
        this.quantity++;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((description == null) ? 0 : description.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        MyItem other = (MyItem) obj;
        if (description == null)
        {
            if (other.description != null)
                return false;
        }
        else if (!description.equals(other.description))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have implement the `equals` method (and it is common to then also implement the `hash` method) to easily be able to check if an item exists in the list (for simplicity, I assume that the `description` uniquely identifies an item, you should change this as needed). You can then continue with your processing like this:

```
public void queryForItem(String itemCode)
{
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT code,desc,price FROM TbLPrice WHERE code =" + itemCode, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        processCursor(cursor);
    }
    cursor.close();
}

private void processCursor(Cursor c)
{
    MyItem newItem = new MyItem();
    newItem.setDescription(c.getString(1));
    newItem.setPrice(c.getFloat(2));
    newItem.setQuantity(1);

    // assuming that items (ArrayList<MyItem>) is defined and initialized earlier in the code
    int existingItemIndex = items.indexOf(newItem);
    if (existingItemIndex >= 0)
    {
        items.get(existingItemIndex).increaseQuantity();
    }
    else
    {
        items.add(newItem);
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I haven't tested this in any way, but I thing it should do what you want. Hope you're able to see the logic in it :)

Comment: thanks for the help, but my arraylist is declared as this : list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); got errors on the list.get(existingItemIndex).increaseQuantity();

Comment: I tried to apply but still. it only updates 2 times on the third time it creates a new same list item. I think the logical error comes on the search if item exists. because on the code. it searches the list with item A, quantity = 1, so after it updates to item A, quantity = 2. it cant search item A with quantity 1 so it creates a new list item A, quantity = 1 and so on

Comment: I suggested to replace your `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` with an `ArrayList<MyItem>`, where you use the custom `MyItem` instead of having to mess around with values in a `HashMap`. Checking whether an item already exists in the list depends on the implementation of the `equals` method in `MyItem`. As I wrote, for simplicity I use the `description` to compare two items, but you would perhaps like to change that (to use an ID for instance). Also remember to be make you don't re-create the list or anything else that makes it reset at some point in your program...

Comment: can you tell me what hashcode() and equals(Object obj) does.
i guess i'm missing that part

Comment: `equals` and `hashCode` are basic Java knowledge, so I recommend reading up on this :) Overriding `equals` is for instance necessary if you want to correctly check for duplicates/existing items in your list of custom items. You can read more about them here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273.html or simply google for "java equals hashcode"

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution, however if an item exist it only update the quantity 2 times on 3rd try It creates new list item with same desc, price but 1 quantity.

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT code,desc,price FROM TbLPrice WHERE code =" + txtCode.getText().toString(), null);  //search database
            if (c.moveToFirst()){ //if successful
                txtDesc.setText(c.getString(1)); //get desc 
                txtPrice.setText(c.getString(2)); // get price @ database
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("desc", c.getString(1));
                map.put("price", c.getString(2));

if(list.isEmpty()){
                    map.put("quantity","1");
                    list.add(map);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else{
                    if(list.contains(map)){
                        int loc = list.indexOf(map);
                        Object o = list.get(loc);
                        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                        HashMap<String, String> map2 = (HashMap<String, String>)o;
                        String b = (String) map2.get("quantity");
                        int quantity = Integer.parseInt(b) + 1;
                        map2.put("quantity", Integer.toString(quantity));
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                    else{
                        map.put("quantity","1");
                        list.add(map);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
```