# How to get value of specific key from listview using entry

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, hashmap

I facing a problem of `getting all the value from specific key` of hashmap listview. I have two listview here, the first listview is to display the data that get from the database and the second listview is to get the data that selected from the first listview. And now, I wish to get all the value of (FOODID3, itemID) from the second listview to display via toast, but I can only get the latest value received from first listview currently. I think the problem is because I set the notifyDataSetChanged on adapter. Please help! Thanks!

This is my first listview that get the data from database

```
private void listMenu(String CID)
{               
    ArrayList<Object> data = DB.getFood(CID);

    LIST2 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i=i+4)
    {   
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        map.put(FOODID2, (String) data.get(i));
        map.put(FOODNAME2, (String) data.get(i+1));
        map.put(PRICE2, (String) data.get(i+2));
        map.put(RATING2, (String) data.get(i+3));

        LIST2.add(map);
    }

    LISTMENU = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMenu);

    final List2Adapter adapter = new List2Adapter(MainActivity.this, LIST2);
    LISTMENU.setAdapter(adapter);


    LISTMENU.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {

            HashMap<String, String> map = LIST2.get(position);

            itemValue = map.get(FOODNAME2);
            itemID = map.get(FOODID2);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Food ID : " + itemID + "ListItem : " + itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

            listOrder(itemValue, itemID);
         }
    });
}
```

This is the second listview that receive the data selected from first listview.

```
private void listOrder(String itemValue, String itemID)
{   
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String quantity = "1";

    map.put(FOODID3, itemID);
    map.put(FOODNAME3, itemValue);  
    map.put(FOODQUANTITY3, quantity);

    //problem is here, I can only display the latest data received
    for(Entry<String, String> entry: map.entrySet())
    {
        if(entry.getKey().equals(FOODID3))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "EXISTS "  + entry.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
        }
    }

    LIST3.add(map);

    LISTORDER = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOrder);

    List3Adapter adapter = new List3Adapter(MainActivity.this, LIST3);
    LISTORDER.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    LISTORDER.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: a map cannot contain several values for a given key.

Answer (score 2):

your map **can contain duplicate values** but **can not contain duplicate keys**

each time you add element with the existing key name, it overwrites the old value with the new one

please go through [Oracle Tutorials - Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Actually I have very similar problem like this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900281/updating-list-hashmap

I want to check if the itemID that get from the first listview selected is already exists in second listview, the quantity++

So now I still trying to get all value from the key of FOODID3 by using toast to do testing on what I get from the for loop

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand do you want to append the third food item to the map? If so you should initialize the map again and anyway this is the wrong way to do it, you should also create a Food object and create an HashMap of Food objects instead of put all the key=>values into it.